# Laravel, unable to copyDirectory or moveDirectory

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems

Currently I having problem with Laravel cannot use moveDirectory and copyDirectory however makeDirectory or deleteDirectory works fine, the code as follow:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Property;

use Intervention;

class PropertyController extends Controller {

    public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        $property = Property::findOrFail($id);
        $oldName  = $property->name;

        $property->fill($request->all());
        if ($request->name == '') {
            $property->name = str_slug($request->title);
        }
        $property->updated_by = Auth::user()->username;

        if ($oldName !== $property->name) {
            Storage::disk('public')->moveDirectory('images/'.$oldName, 'images/'.$property->name);
        }
        $property->save();

        show_feedback('info', 'Property successfully updated');

        return redirect(route('property-management.index'));
    }
}
```

with error:

```
BadMethodCallException in PluggableTrait.php line 85:
Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::moveDirectory
```

Comment: you have to use File::copyDirectory($sourceDir, $destinationDir); for that, try and let me know ?

Comment: I already tested it and works, thanks

Comment: You are welcome :) I have added my answer, Plese upvote my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess `moveDirectory` is not available under `Storage`. Try with below code

import file system first

```
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
```

after that create a new instance and move directory. Path is relative to index.php I guess.

```
$file = new Filesystem();
$file->moveDirectory('../storage/app/public/old_folder', '../storage/app/public/new_folder');
```

Edited

You can bypass instance creation with method injection

```
public function update(Request $request,Filesystem $file, $id)
```

Comment: I use Facade\File currently, but it works more or less

Answer (score 0):

Use the `File::copyDirectory()` method.

> $success = File::copyDirectory($sourceDir, $destinationDir);

The method will return **true** if all files and subdirectories are successfully copied.

If the destination directory doesn't exist it will be created. It will be created recursively as needed.