# Moving Folders in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

**Scenario**

Im trying to allow users to move folders around in laravel 5.5, but Laravels site does not have example code for moving folders only files. I looked elsewhere and came across a couple other answers on stackoverflow and other places and tried them all.

[Laravel move all files directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555402/laravel-move-all-files-directory)

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-cannot-use-movedirectory-and-copydirectory-problem

[Laravel, unable to copyDirectory or moveDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399340/laravel-unable-to-copydirectory-or-movedirectory)

When I try to move a folder i get this response in Devtools:

```
0:"I want to move this /public/Gallery"
1:"To here /public/Images"
2:false
```

From this code in the backend

```
$item ['path' => '/public/Gallery']
$path = '/public/Images'
$success = File::moveDirectory($item['path'], $path);
return [
    "I want to move this ".$item['path'],
    "To here $path",
    $success,
];
```

Earlier i was getting a response that said the file already exists although it didnt but ive not since been able to replicate that.

**EDIT**

using `Storage::move()` i was able to replicate the 'already exists error'

```
exception:"League\Flysystem\FileExistsException"
file:"C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\electron-api\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Filesystem.php"
line:402
message:"File already exists at path: public/Images"
```

**Question**

How to move folders around in laravel 5 storage, NOT FILES. Preferably using the Storage Facade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feel really stupid was using the Method wrongly, Because i didnt see it explicitly referenced anywhere that you had to include the folder name in both the "move from" and "move to" directories essentially, i've been putting this:

`Storage::move('Folder', 'OtherFolder');`

But this doesnt work, i need to do it like this

`Storage::move('Folder', 'OtherFolder/Folder');`

The folder being moved into `OtherFolder` still needs to be named folder, so the name needs to append at the end, laravel wasnt throwing any specific errors that allowed me to understand what i was doing wrong properly.

Hopefully this helps anyone as daft as me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Files and directories are mostly the same thing and move will treat them as the same. 
You can create a local disk that points to public so that it is easier to work with the public directory

```
Storage::move($item['path'], $path);
```

The move function works like bash mv command which is essentially just a rename. 2 directories cannot have the same name. so either first delete public/Images/ or merge contents into public/Images and delete public/Gallery

if you wish to move the directory into $path then you have to place the directory name at the end of the path

```
Storage::move($item['path'], $path.'/Gallery');
```

this will create '/public/Images/Gallery'

Comment: Thats what i did before! and heres the error message i get, exception
:
"League\Flysystem\FileExistsException"
file
:
"C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\electron-api\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Filesystem.php"
line
:
402
message
:
"File already exists at path: public/Images"

Comment: the move works like mv command in linux which is essentially just a rename